# Помогите, как сделать так, как на картинке, какой использовать JS плагин или как написать на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, плагин

[image: На картинке показан итоговый результат, который необходимо достигнуть]

Пытался найти в интернете ответ, но не смог нормально сформулировать свой вопрос, сформулировал как мог, но ничего не нашлось.

Comment: slick.js  - в котором активный слайд не прозрачный а все остальные чуть меньше и прозраные

Comment: swiper slider --